# No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk, build.gradle

I'm Trying to generate android project from ionic in my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS in Webstorm with this command:

```
 sudo ionic cordova build android
```

I have defined the following variables in the .bashrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/matteo/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/matteo/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/matteo/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/matteo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```

and i ran the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

But I still have the following errors:

```
Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '..../platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

this is my SDK situation:

[image]

If i run this command:

```
cordova requirements android --verbose
```

this is the result:

```
Platform API successfully found in: .../platforms/android/cordova/Api.js
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-30,android-29,android-27,android-22
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

Comment: `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable is not set.

Comment: Thanks Najam. I set variables in /etc/environment and now i solve the problem.